# What is a programmers reference book?

Tags: java

I am going to take a Java application class, and I have to purchase a Java programming book.

When I went to [Amazon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon.com) it showed that some of the people who purchased the book also bought a Java reference book. What is the difference between the Java programming book and a Java reference book?

Comment: not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

A reference book is usually used by someone who already knows the language and need to lookup a particular function or syntax. A programming book will teach you how to program in that language.

Answer (score 2):

This analogy may seem stretched but follow it through. Programming is the application of algorithms (abstract logical operations) like recipes for cooking (or preparing) food. A reference manual is a comprehensive list of ingredients and things that can cook them. In contrast, a programming manual teaches you how to cook.

Answer (score 0):

Like the name suggests, a reference book is for reference. You will need it when you are stuck somewhere when programming. It just gives you the basic syntax usually. It doesn't teach you "how to program"; all it has is "what to type".

It assumes that you know the language. A programmer's book teaches you how to program and is a step-by-step approach. If you are a beginner (intermediate), then I would suggest you to have a look at "Thinking in Java " by Bruce Eckel. It is one of the best books I have ever seen. It also teaches you some important concepts of [object-oriented design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_design).